# How to extract and use @timefield from my log file?

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, tokenize, filebeat, elk

I wish to set the @timestamp field to read timestamps from my log lines instead of using the time when it read the log how can I do this.

example log lines:

```
2021.04.21 00:00:00.843  INF  getBaseData: UserName = 'nou dont look', Password = 'psps', HTTPS=0
2021.04.21 00:00:00.843  INF  getBaseData: UserName = 'you bad bad', Password = 'grign', HTTPS=0
2021.04.21 00:00:00.843  INF  getBaseData: UserName = 'ayooooo', Password = 'butter sauce', HTTPS=0
2021.04.21 00:00:00.858  INF  *** BEGINNING OF ARCCore.performARCTask ***
2021.04.21 00:00:00.858  INF  *** BEGINNING OF ARCCore.ProcessTask ***
2021.04.21 00:00:01.266  INF  ARCCore.DCI4ARCSyncLogin: login successfully executed. - No error - DCI4ARCSync-CurrSessions/MaxSessions=17/400 CurrProcesses/MaxProcesses=16/250
2021.04.21 00:00:01.297  INF  ARCCore.DCI4ARCSyncLogin: login successfully executed. - No error - DCI4ARCSync-CurrSessions/MaxSessions=7/400 CurrProcesses/MaxProcesses=7/250
2021.04.21 00:00:08.165  INF  ***  BEGINNING OF SYNC ARC TO DC  ***--->bIsExternal:0
2021.04.21 00:00:08.434  INF  BOC login successfully executed.  - No Error - DCI4ARC-CurrSessions/MaxSessions=24/400 CurrProcesses/MaxProcesses=15/250
2021.04.21 00:00:08.635  INF  BOCVersionNr ==> V16.1.00.00
2021.04.21 00:00:08.804  INF  setEntitySnapshot successfully executed
2021.04.21 00:00:09.453  INF  getSnapshotList successfully executed
2021.04.21 00:00:09.461  INF  getARCVersion: ARCVersionNr ==> V16.0.00.06
```

I use the following tokenizers to dissect log lines :

processors:

```
- dissect:
    when:
      contains:
        message: "UserName"
    tokenizer: "%{timestamplog} %{+timestamplog}  %{type}  %{func}: UserName = 'ARC_%{trash1}_%{trash2}_%{trash3}, Password = '%{password}', HTTPS=%{https}"
    target_prefix: "axess"
    


- dissect:
    when:
      contains:
        message: "BOCVersionNr"
    tokenizer: "%{timestamplog} %{+timestamplog}  %{type}  BOCVersionNr ==> %{BOCversionNr|ip}"
    target_prefix: "axess"



- dissect:
    when:
      contains:
        message: "ARCVersionNr"
    tokenizer: "%{timestamplog} %{+timestamplog}  %{type}  getARCVersion: ARCVersionNr ==> %{ARCVersionNr|ip}"
    target_prefix: "axess"


- dissect:
    when:
      contains:
        message: "ERR"
    tokenizer: "%{timestamplog} %{+timestamplog}  %{type}  %{ErrMsg}"
    target_prefix: "axess"


- dissect:
    when:
      contains:
        message: "INF"
    tokenizer: "%{timestamplog} %{+timestamplog}  %{type}  %{InfMsg}"
    target_prefix: "axess"
```

Now what I wish to achieve is that in kibana as my @timestamp I use values from the axess.timestamplog field, so that I could apply ranges and other time related operations with the data.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [rename](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/rename-fields.html) processor. To remane you event into `@timestamp`.

If you wish to keep this information in `axess.timestamplog` you may want to use the [copy processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/copy-fields.html).

They are many solutions, also directly in Elasticsearch by tweaking the index settings. But as you do not mention this in your question I considered it off topic.

Comment: Thank you! How would I do this if I chose to do it directly in Elasticsearch?